# javascript code formatter and highlighter

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

I am looking for a jQuery plugin that can take a string of code as input and will apply formatting and Highlights to make the code easily understandable. Just like jsfiddle.net.
As of now I have found many sites like jsbeautifier.org..  But I need a standalone jquery plugin which can process my code
Please help me on this.

Comment: Why does it have to be a jquery plugin?

Comment: This might work: http://shjs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: :-) Cause I am already using jQuery library.. Some buddies may suggest prototype and mootools plugins.

Comment: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/16-free-javascript-code-syntax-highlighters-for-better-programming/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[9 useful Javascript syntax highilghting scripts](http://www.360doc.com/content/10/0110/15/383978_13168406.shtml). There, I googled it for you. 3 of them are jQuery-based.

Comment: I got lucky and end up here ;)

Comment: Which of them do formatting besides highlighting?

Comment: SHJS works great :) Thank you for this link!

Comment: For lots of reasons the one form Google will be preferred by most:


https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Comment: it's a broken link

Comment: @theEpsilon: Thanks, updated. Can't really say it's the exact same scripts, but the article is from 2010 and has the exact same title, so I guess it may well be. I get that link-only answers aren't ideal, but OP is asking for an external software, and those are bound to be links, and the question is from 2011, so some of them are bound to be broken.

Answer (score 4):

i am using codemirror.
 http://codemirror.net/

its easy and cool.

Comment: CodeMirror is very extensible. Lots of projects use it: http://codemirror.net/doc/realworld.html

Comment: but I don't see a formatting addon. It has fantastic stuff like code completion et al but no formatting function that I can find.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Highlight.Js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)

Comment: this one really works well for me. I had function to remove extra tab and newlines in my pre, so the other plugin couldn't work properly because of this method. But hightlight.js work well with my function :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the syntax in a specific style or just check the style than take a look at **[code painter](https://github.com/jedmao/codepainter)**

> A JavaScript beautifier that can both infer coding style and transform
>   code to reflect that style. You can also set style preferences
>   explicitly in a variety of ways.

Comment: Looks cool. Haven't seen much examples though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jstidy](http://code.google.com/p/jstidy/) for this. and if you are using visual studio, you can directly copy code and paste in to the designer view. it will generates the required styles.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the pages linked by other answers and found them very lacking.

After a bit of research and scouring the web, [I found one](http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/) that I think clearly is superior to the rest.

[**Snippit**](http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/) is jQuery based, including "copy" feature (with clipboard plugin), line-numbers, custom styles, etc.

Let me know what you think.